# Angular component function call

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-components

I have an issue, How can we call a function from name.component.html file without (button click) either to .ts file or to service.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a workaround with jquery, but it is not a best practice.

HTML:

```
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#target" ).click();

$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```